# Why won't a class derived from an abstract class with a where clause cast to its lowest common class

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract-class

Some code to replicate the issue:

```
using System;

public abstract class Response { }
public abstract class Request<T> where T : Response { }
public class LoginResponse : Response { }
public class LoginRequest : Request<LoginResponse> { }

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        LoginRequest login = new LoginRequest();


        /* Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'LoginRequest' to 'Request' */
        Request<Response> castTest = login;


        /* No Error */
        Request<LoginResponse> castTest2 = login;
    }
}
```

As far as i can tell the LoginRequest class is a Request<Response> because is inherits from Request<T> and LoginResponse inherits from Response so can anybody enlighten me as to why i get the compiler error?

note: i have also tried an explicit cast

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're getting the error because `Request<Response>` and `Request<LoginResponse>` are not covariant.

Just because `LoginResponse` inherits from `Response` doesn't mean that `Request<LoginResponse>` can be treated the same as `Request<Response>`. Give this article a read:

[MSDN - Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, my understanding of covariance is a bit thin i need to do more reading.

Answer (score 7):

Because your generic parameter is implicitly invariant - the two types, `Request<LoginResponse>` and `Request<Response>` are completely distinct. C# 4.0 introduced variance in delegate types and interfaces and can provide a solution for you here:

```
public interface IResponse<out T> where T : Response {}
```

Here we have declared the generic type `T` as [Covariant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29).

Eric Lippert has written [many good blog posts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/covariance+and+contravariance/default.aspx) on the topic of variance in C#, I'd highly recommend reading them.

Answer (score 7):

This is because C# generic classes are not covariant.  C# is trying to keep you from doing the following:

```
Request<Response> castTest = login;
castTest.Response = someOtherKindOfResponse;
```

This example is perhaps more clear with Lists.  Imagine if the following worked:

```
var someStringList = new List<String>();
var someObjectList = ((List<Object>)someStringList; // This throws a compile exception, thankfully
someObjectList.Add(1); // If the above worked, then this would compile, but would throw a runtime exception
```

Comment: I like the list example it makes it simpler to understand.

Answer (score 3):

`LoginRequest` does not derive from `Request<Response>`, it derives from `Request<LoginResponse>`.

A generic type is a type in itself once compiled. The templated parameter hierarchy is irrelevant.